# Weird browser behaviour with HTML anchors in C# WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, anchor

I have a WebBrowser control which I populate with HTML then display. The HTML contains a few links pointing to anchors in the same page...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="#myTarget">jump</a>

        <!-- further down page -->
        <a name="myTarget"><h2>A heading</h2></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. If I run my app via Visual Studio and load the control the HTML is displayed no problem. I click on a link and it jumps to the anchor as it should.
2. Ditto if I install my app onto my local machine (ie installed via an MSI not run via Visual Studio). Everything as expected so far.
3. However if I install and run my application in a WinXP virtual machine the HTML is still displayed as expected but now when I click on a link it behaves as if jumping to a new page. This new page simply contains...

.

```
<html>
    blank#myTarget
</html>
```

The  tags in the HTML generated by my app are exactly the same as I've included in my sample code above.

Could this be a C# issue? Is there a setting of the WebBrowser control I need to edit perhaps?

**Update: Internet Explorer 6.0

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, can you please post the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the same version of IE on all testing platforms.